# How to store the current state of InteractiveInterpreter Object in a database?

Tags: python, interactive-shell, python-interactive

I am trying to build an online Python Shell. I execute commands by creating an instance of `InteractiveInterpreter` and use the command `runcode`. For that I need to store the interpreter state in the database so that variables, functions, definitions and other values in the global and local namespaces can be used across commands. Is there a way to store the current state of the object `InteractiveInterpreter` that could be retrieved later and passed as an argument `local` to `InteractiveInterpreter` constructor or If I can't do this, what alternatives do I have to achieve the mentioned functionality?
Below is the pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve

```
def fun(code, sessionID):
     session = Session()
     # get the latest state of the interpreter object corresponding to SessionID
     vars = session.getvars(sessionID)
     it = InteractiveInterpreter(vars)
     it.runcode(code)
     #save back the new state of the interpreter object
     session.setvars(it.getState(),sessionID)
```

Here, session is an instance of table containing all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `pickle` package should work for you. You can use `pickle.dump` or `pickle.dumps` to save the state of most objects. (then `pickle.load` or `pickle.loads` to get it back)

Comment: I tried this. But sadly, InteractiveInterpreter is an unpickable ibject.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if pickle doesn't work, you might try re-instantiating the class, with a format (roughly) like below:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, OldClass):
        for d in dir(OldClass):
            # go through the attributes from the old class and set
            # the new attributes to what you need
```